# Combine key and values of a MAP

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am trying to solve a problem and I get my result on the format Map[String, (Double,Double)].

I am wondering is there a way to convert it to Map[String, Double,Double] as I want to sort it by string ?

More specifically, I would like to sort it as following:

```
("A1", (7.8,9.2))
("A2", (4.2,44.3))
("A11", (9,54.1))
```

If I were to use SortedMap I get sth like:

```
("A1", (7.8,9.2))
("A11", (9,54.1))
("A2", (4.2,44.3))
```

which is not the desired result.

P.S: I would like to convert the map in an appropriate format so that I could apply:

```
sortBy((x:String)=>(x.substring(1).toInt))
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: `Map[String,Double,Double]` isn't correct Scala syntax so it's hard to tell what you actually want to achieve. Can you provide an example? (Add it to your question via the "edit" link.)

Comment: You can use a SortedMap.
`SortedMap[String, (Double, Double)](("h1",(1,3)), ("h2",(1,3)), ("a",(1,3)))`

Comment: Map is a datastructure with a key and a value, Are you looking for Multi-map?

Comment: I was going to comment the same as @ShankarShastri, so just complementing his comment, [here](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/SortedMap.html) is the scaladoc for **SortedMap**. And a simple example showing how to convert a map _(m)_ to a sorted map _(sm)_. `val sm = SortedMap.empty[String, (Double, Double)] ++ m`.

Comment: what exactly you want to do can you add some example.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers!! I updated the question provided an example. Apologies!!

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understood you want to sort your map by the key. you can do like this

```
val inputMap = Map(
A1->(7.8,9.2),
A11-> (9,54.1),
A2-> (4.2,44.3)
)
val outputMap = inputMap.toSeq.sortBy(_._1.split("A")(1).toInt).toList
println(outputMap) //List((A1,(7.8,9.2)), (A2,(4.2,44.3)), (A11,(9,54.1)))
```

**provided that the key will always have the same format like A+number ex. "A5" is valid AA1 is not.**

if you want your answer as list of tuple (key, value) you can do outputMap.toSeq or toList.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!! What I used is: `.toSeq.sortBy(_._1.substring(1).toInt).foreach{println}` ,however we need to convert to Seq in order to convert it?

Comment: @Andros yes because we will get a vactor if you want it to be a list will have to do .toList or Seq.

Answer (score 0):

```
 val ex = Map(("A1", (7.8,9.2))
            ,("A2", (4.2,44.3))
            ,("A11", (9.0,54.1)))


Without changing the format of the Map, using

 ex.toList.sortBy(x=>x._1.substring(1).toInt)
```

If you want the result by *changing* the `Map[String,(Double,Double)]` to `Map[String,Double,Double]`, using

```
 ex.map{case (a,(b,c))=>(a,b,c)}.toList.sortBy(x=>x._1.substring(1).toInt)
```

***In Scala REPL:***

```
scala> ex.toList.sortBy(x=>x._1.substring(1).toInt)
res97: List[(String, (Double, Double))] = List((A1,(7.8,9.2)), (A2,(4.2,44.3)), (A11,(9.0,54.1)))

scala> ex.map{case (a,(b,c))=>(a,b,c)}.toList.sortBy(x=>x._1.substring(1).toInt)
res96: List[(String, Double, Double)] = List((A1,7.8,9.2), (A2,4.2,44.3), (A11,9.0,54.1))
```